# Completely removing remnants of postgres 9.6 install

Tags: macos, postgresql

So I had version 9.6 installed locally, but wanted to match our production servers which are 9.5. So I did what I thought was a full uninstall of 9.6, installed 9.5, and tried to restore a database locally from the server. The issue is that the restore looks for the extensions in a path for 9.6 (which does not exist anymore):

"ERROR: could not open extension control file "/Users/*currentuser*/PostgreSQL/pg96/share/postgresql/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what resolved this, but it is no longer an issue.